# Support the last one left

Tags: word, pattern, knowledge, cryptic-clues, sports

The enumerations of these four crossword clues are related:

> 1. Naughty streamer even I watch.
> 2. Justify the new mass rite.
> 3. Not a grey cap on the board?
> 4. Send up Queen's University.

Find a fifth word following the answer pattern, and name who was finally awarded this World Cup.

Comment: Updated the first clue to remove an indirect anagram - apologies for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naughty streamer even I watch.

> **TIMER** (watch) — anagram ("naughty") of .T.E.M.R (even letters of "streamer") and I

Justify the new mass rite.

> **MERIT** (justify) — anagram ("new") of M (*m*, "mass" in physics) and RITE.

Not a grey cap on the board?

> **MITRE** — I'm not sure here. A mitre is a cap where two boards join at an angle. It is also a bishop's hat, and a bishop is a man on a chess board? "Not a" suggests that A can be inserted to MITRE to make a word meaning grey. The word is "maître", but I can't see its relation to grey.

Send up Queen's University.

> **REMIT** (send) — reversal ("up") of ER (*Elizabeth Regina*, queen) + MIT (University in Cambridge, Massachusetts)

Notice a pattern?

> These are all anagrams of each other. We are looking for a fifth one. (There's miter, but that's only the American spelling of mitre, so let's discount that.)
>
>  [Jules **Rimet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Rimet) was the FIFA president who introduced the Association Football World Cup tournament. The original [World Cup Trophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup_Trophy) is called the Jules Rimet Cup in his honour. In 1970, it was awarded permanently to **Brazil**, the first team to win it three times.

Comment: Technically incorrect, because Belgium beat Brazil and cannot win this World Cup :P

Comment: Man of the Match award to M Oehm. My third was lightly clued - just that the cap in the board game belongs to a bishop and so is B or W so not grey (I know this is not great). Top explanations and the title's a clue to your final answer too.